# SQL query Failed

Tags: mysql, mariadb

please give me recommendation my query does not working

SQL query:

```
CREATE TABLE `amenities` (
  `amenities_id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `pic` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `des` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`amenities_id`)
) TYPE=MariaDB  AUTO_INCREMENT=13
```

MySQL said: Documentation

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'TYPE=MariaDB  AUTO_INCREMENT=13' at line 6

Comment: what did you want with `AUTO_INCREMENT=13`? This is the error pointed by the message

Comment: @Leonardo Alves Machado And why not if he wants to? And it's not the error, it's near the error.

Answer (score 4):

There is no type table option, you possibly want to define the table engine 
and there is no mariadb engine try

```
CREATE TABLE amenities (  amenities_id int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment, 
 pic varchar(100) NOT NULL,  des text NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (amenities_id) ) 
 AUTO_INCREMENT=13,
 engine=innodb
```

Or leave out the engine option if you want to default the table to the database engine/

Answer (score 0):

Hope this works.

```
CREATE TABLE amenities (  
    amenities_id int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
    pic varchar(100) NOT NULL,  
    des text NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (amenities_id) 
)  AUTO_INCREMENT=13
```

Answer (score 0):

- The `TYPE` keyword was replaced by `ENGINE` long ago.
- The `ENGINEs` are `InnoDB`, `MyISAM`, `MEMORY`, `ARIA` and possibly others.  Not `MySQL`, nor `MariaDB`.
- The error message `... near 'TYPE ...` points exactly at or after the offending syntax: `TYPE` in this case.  (Not `AUTO_INCREMENT`, which was later)
- `AUTO_INCREMENT=13` is produced by `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for possible reloading.  However, it is rarely useful otherwise.  It is also mostly harmless.

Answer (score 0):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `amenities`;

CREATE TABLE `amenities` (
  `amenities_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `pic` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `des` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`amenities_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Create new Table `amenities` where `amenities_id` is a PRIMARY KEY that will be auto increment. another table field `pic` is a varchar data type and `des` is a text data type that is used for rich text.

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.